# A probability/measure theory problem on inner and outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I need to find a subset $A$ in $[0,1]$ such that $P^*(A)=1$ and $P^*(A^c)=1$ where

where $P^*(A) = inf_{n}\sum P(I_n)$ where $\{I_n\}$ is a cover of $A$. and $P(I_n)$ = length of the closed interval $I_n$.

Comment: Hint: This is a set theory problem.

Comment: @i707107: I guess that both $A$ and $A^c$ must be dense.

Comment: In fact, they should be non measurable.. So you have to use the Axiom of Choice somewhere (and I think that's what i707107 tried to say...)

Comment: To expand on the hint given by @i707107: If $A$ has the property that for every Borel set $B$ with $0<\mu(B)<1$ there is a point in $B$ that is in $A$ and a point in $B$ that is in $A^C$, $A$ solves the problem.